# Variable.map is not a function React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on app and I am trying to extract three attributes of this string (I thought it was an array of objects is `filteredResultsJSON`, but it is a string) :

[image]

Well, when I want to get the news of a given section I am using this code:

```
export default function getNewsFilteredBySection (sectionSearched="") {

    const URL= `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/viewed/7.json?api-key=${API_KEY}`;
   
    
  return fetch(URL)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(response=> {
            const { data = [] } = response;
            if(Array.isArray(data)){
                const {results} = response; 
                const filteredResults = results.filter(obj => {
                    return obj.section === sectionSearched;
                  });
                const filteredResultsJSON = JSON.stringify(filteredResults);
                const name = typeof(filteredResultsJSON);
                console.log(name);
                return filteredResultsJSON;
            }
        })


};
```

I did `JSON.stringify(filteredResults)` because I saw it when doing `console.log()`as an `[Object Object]` and I wanted to be able to read the information and to loop through it to be able to extract it.

So I am using this code to extract the attributes I want for each news:

```
export function getNewsAttributes (filteredResultsJSON=[]) {
        const newsAttributes = filteredResultsJSON.map(filteredResultJSON=>{
            const { title, abstract, url } = filteredResultJSON;
            console.log(title, abstract, url);
            return {title, abstract, url}; 
          });
        return newsAttributes;
};
```

But it returns the following error:

[image]

I have been researching and I totally think the matter is about `JSON.Stringify(filteredResults)`. How could I maintain that variable as an object, being able to read it and extract the information from it?

I am going to use it like this, after an `onClick` event:

```
function showEvent (e) {
      const sectionSearched = e.target.innerText;
      const filteredResultsJSON = getNewsFilteredBySection(sectionSearched);
      const newsAttributes = getNewsAttributes(filteredResultsJSON);

    }
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: We need more information; what's in `filteredResultsJSON`?

Comment: Seems like `filteredResultsJSON` isn't something with `map` on it, like `null` or `undefined` or `12`, but we don't know either :) Unrelated, but I might use 1) a shorter variable name (like `results`) and something equally concise for the `map` function parameter.

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: It's unlikely that's what's being passed to `getNewsAttributes`, because an array has `map`. If this is an async request are you sure `getNewsAttributes` is being called only after the request completes?

Comment: We can at least rule out `undefined`, as you have a default parameter.

Comment: FilteredResultsJSON is that array of object (i show in the image) and i receive it from an async call that is done before the execution of getNewsAttributes.

Comment: That's fairly unlikely, since an array has `map`. This is easy to test by printing out the JSON content of `filteredResultsJSON` on entry, e.g., `console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredResultsJSON))` as the first line of `getNewsAttributes`. This will make it clearer what is happening and the console won't fill in the value retroactively once the async call completes.

Comment: You were right is a string. I have updated all the edition of the question, I am researching how to solve it, some help is welcome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
export default function getNewsFilteredBySection (sectionSearched="") {

    const URL= `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/viewed/7.json?api-key=${API_KEY}`;
   
    
  return fetch(URL)
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(response=> {
            const { data = [] } = response;
            if(Array.isArray(data)){
                const {results} = response; 
                const filteredResults = results.filter(obj => {
                    return obj.section === sectionSearched;
                  });
                console.log(filteredResults);
                return filteredResults;
            }
        })


};
```

Finally I didnt need to do `JSON.Stringify(filteredResults)`. However I am having this two errors and I dont know why, my app works:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add async

```
export default async function getNewsFilteredBySection (sectionSearched=""){ ...


showEvent = async (e) => { ...
```

and await

```
const filteredResultsJSON = await getNewsFilteredBySection(sectionSearched);
```

Comment: If I do that it doesnt work and it says "unexpected reserved word 'await'":     

```function showEvent (e) {
      const sectionSearched = e.target.innerText;
      const filteredResults = getNewsFilteredBySection(sectionSearched);
      const newsAttributes = await getNewsAttributes(filteredResults);
      console.log(newsAttributes);

    }```

Comment: Also async function showEvent. But you will still have the cross origin error.

Comment: Show Event is triggered by a onClick event. If I write async function show event it returns me error, it says I need to write ), but that doesnt make sense.